# Plotting count in geom_text after a geom_bar when proportions are unbalanced with position="fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I want to plot the following `mock.data` with a plot similar as the following:

```
# mock data    
mock.data <- data.frame(
      patient=c(rep("Healthy", 9925), rep("Sick", 75)),
      drug=c(rep(c("A", "B"), 5000)))

# plot code
    ggplot(mock.data, aes(y=patient, fill=drug))+
      geom_bar(position="fill")+
      geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = after_stat(count), 
                                    x = after_stat(count)/sum(after_stat(count)), 
                                    group=drug),
                position=position_stack(0.5))+
 xlab("proportion")
```

With the following output:
[image]

The problem is that when adding a `geom_text` with `after_stat("count")`, with my code, the labels for the `sick` group locate on the x axis according to their proportion respect to the four groups, not only `sick` or `healthy`. The particularity in this case is the huge disproportion between the groups, which pushed the `sick` values to 0.

All the solutions I've found to solve this precompute the proportion by group separately before plotting but I think this is not optimal.

Therefore, I wonder if there is any possible solution, for example modifying somehow the data directly inside the ggplot using its own parameters.

Comment: We've been all there - but it is rather typical beginners thinking to consider pre-computing stuff outside of ggplot2 would be suboptimal. It isn't! It's the most straight forward and least error-prone thing to do. You don't need to be afraid of pre-computing stuff. It doesn't cost you memory, in contrary, you might create data objects that you will need several times and thus **saves** you computing time/memory.

Comment: I was hoping for some magical way to do this straightforward, but I'll take your advice

Comment: `position=position_fill(vjust = 0.5))+` will match the position = fill of the other layer.

Comment: @JonSpring if I'm not wrong this would only work when the two levels inside each bar are quite similar. In a hypothetical case of 75%-25% the labels would look already biased.

Comment: Try it, I think it will work; the 0.5 relates to the spacing of the label within each bar, not the overall spacing. eg. `mock.data <- data.frame(
  patient=c(rep("Healthy", 9925), rep("Sick", 75)),
  drug=c(sample(c("A", "B"), replace = TRUE, size = 5000, prob = c(0.2, 0.8))))` output looks fine to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the bars are positioned with "fill", which takes the computed values and scales them to the 0-1 range, we should use the same for the geom_text layer. `position = "fill"` is equivalent to `position = position_fill()`, but if we use the latter we can specify further parameters, like in this case `vjust` specifies how far along in each bar the text should be placed.

```
mock.data <- data.frame(
  patient=c(rep("Healthy", 9925), rep("Sick", 75)),
  drug=c(sample(c("A", "B"), replace = TRUE, size = 5000, prob = c(0.2, 0.8))))

# plot code
ggplot(mock.data, aes(y=patient, fill=drug))+
  geom_bar(position="fill")+
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = after_stat(count), 
                                x = after_stat(count)/sum(after_stat(count)), 
                                group=drug),
            position=position_fill(vjust = 0.5))+
  xlab("proportion")
```

[image]

Comment: I see that in this case `x=after_stat(count)/sum(after_stat(count))` can be removed and the output is just the same.